# Navigation links not working in navbar (Bootstrap)(Django)

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm creating a website using django 1.10 and python 3.6. 
My web app is called 'profiles' and project is called 'firstsite'. I used a template from bootstrap which is saved as 'base.html'. I have two pages in my webapp which use template 'home.html' and 'about.html'. Navigation bar is another html file called 'navbar.html'. I'm trying to link 'home' and 'about' in navigation bar. After linking, when i runserver and open 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' I get 'NoReverseMatch at/' error.

- **firstsite/firstsite/urls.py**

  ```
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.conf.urls.static import static
  from django.conf.urls import url, include
  from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      url(r'^', include('profiles.urls')),
  ]

  if settings.DEBUG:
      urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
      urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/urls.py**

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from profiles import views

  app_name = 'profiles'
  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
      url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
  ]
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/views.py**

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render

  def home(request):
      context = locals()
      template = 'home.html'
      return render(request, template, context)

  def about(request):
      context = locals()
      template = 'about.html'
      return render(request, template, context)
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/templates/base.html**

  ```
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

      <title>Theme Template for Bootstrap</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
      <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
      <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <link href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/main.css" %}'>

      <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
      <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>


  <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>   
     {% include 'navbar.html'%}
     <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">

     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}

       <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
       <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>Theme example</h1>
         <p>This is a template showcasing the optional theme stylesheet included in Bootstrap. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique by building on or modifying it.</p>
       </div>
     </div> <!-- /container -->


     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
     ================================================== -->
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
     <script src="{% static 'javascript/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
     <script src="{% static 'javascript/docs.min.js' %}"></script>
     <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
     <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/templates/home.html**

  ```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}


  {% block content %}
  <h1>Hello World. I'm Back.</h1>
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/templates/about.html**

  ```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  <h1>Hello About</h1>
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- **firstsite/profiles/templates/navbar.html**

  ```
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  ```

As you can see in navbar.html, {% url 'home' %} should work instead I get this error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMmtj.jpg)

If i remove {% url 'home' %} in navbar.html and place #, the website works fine without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use app name before named urls

```
<li class="active"><a href="{% url 'profiles:home' %}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'profiles:about' %}">About</a></li>
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I feel privileged to help you.@K.Grewal